# Laravel 5.7 cannot connect to mysql after php upgrade to 7.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have a laravel 5.7 installation running on Ubuntu 18 on EC2 and MYSQL RDS.  I have upgraded my PHP from 7.2 to 7.4.  The site runs but pages that pull data from mysql show a 404 error.  But if I revert back to PHP 7.2 they work fine.  Do I need to make any additional code/configuration changes?

Answer (score 0):

After investigating more, it was a simple fix.   I needed to have the mysql driver installed for the latest version of php.

sudo apt install php7.4-common php7.4-mysql php7.4-xml php7.4-xmlrpc php7.4-curl php7.4-gd php7.4-imagick php7.4-cli php7.4-dev php7.4-imap php7.4-mbstring php7.4-opcache php7.4-soap php7.4-zip php7.4-intl -y